# Finding interrogative sentences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nlp

I need to detect whether a given sentence have interrogative characteristics? Is there any available gem(ROR) that implements this with NLP libraries or any current state of art implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "interrogative charactistics"?  (Would the first sentence you wrote above be a statement or a question according to your intended classifier?)

Comment: Interrogative means a sentence asking question as in . "What is ruby?." where as "Rails is a web framework." is not a interrogative question

Comment: But what indicates a question for your task?  A question mark?  Word order?  In your original question, the first sentence has the word order of a statement but ends with a question mark.  The second sentence has the word order of a question but ends with a period.  How would you classify them?

Answer (score 0):

In general NLP code is python or java.

For this problem though I think you could hack together something that's basically - does it start with a W-word, or 'Are' and end with a question mark? More advanced, you could take a few thousand question sentences, create features similar to the quick hack (ie first word, final char) and then train a machine learning model on it. You'd probably do this in python the quickest, and then you could write the model interpreter in ruby (the interpreter is easy).

Or you could just write a simple Naive Bayes classifier!